# jar file generates RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Tags: java, html, netbeans, jar, applet

I'm trying to run a jar file in an HTML page but I can't run it because it immidiately throws a java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException even though the main function is empty and doesn't call any code. How can I fix this?

The code in my HTML page is:

```
   <applet archive="java/WaterDrops.jar" code="waterdrops.Main.class" width="100%" height="100%" title="Java(TM)"></applet>
```

Comment: Probably because of this--->`archive="java/WaterDrops.jar" code="waterdrops.Main.class"`---how come that path of archive be serving the purpose!

Comment: I don't follow you. What do you mean?

Comment: Remove that `jar` file from `java` directory and then try and comment as to what do you get!

Comment: I just added it to a folder called java. When I took it from that folder and put it in the root it still doesn't work. Or isn't that what you mean?

Comment: Is the main class called `Main`?  Is it in the package `waterdrops`?  Is it declared as `public`? Does it `extend Applet` or `extend JApplet`? What is the `caused by` part of the stack trace?

Comment: Why code an applet?  If it is due to spec by your instructor, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Comment: The main class is indeed called Main. I removed it from the package waterdrops, so it is just Main.class. It is now located in a package named <default package> but in code it doesn't state that it is in any specific namespace. The stack trace I cannot access.


import java.applet.Applet;

/**
 *
 * @author deleo
 */
public class Main extends Applet
{
   /**
     * param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
    }
}

Comment: Finally got I working! It turned out to be a settings problem in Netbeans; when I created a new Java project and fiddled with the settings, it finally worked:
http://www.jurvanoerle.nl/waterdrops.html